# BFS using Adjacency Matrix

Tags: graph-theory, asymptotics, computational-complexity

What is the running time of BFS if we represent its input graph by an
adjacency matrix and modify the algorithm to handle this form of input?

I feel if the graph is represented by adjacency matrix, then the time of iterating all the edge becomes O(V^2), so the running time is O(V+V^2).

But I read online that each vertex can be explored once and its adjacent vertices must be determined too. This takes Theta(V^2) time. And now I am confused.
How can we bound the lower limit as well?

Comment: If you do it naively then it is $\mathcal O(v^3)$ time for the complete graph.

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo sorry I did not get you. how come?

Comment: Nevermind, I got confused , you have $\mathcal O (v^2)$ complexity